# Change font color for a sql file on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using the dark theme on Visual Studio 2015, and installed ReSharper 2017 along with it. As you can see the color on a sql extension file is awful with the dark theme and I cannot find where I can modify its color.

[image: the color on a sql file]

Could anyone point me out where to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to tools> options> Environment> Fonts and Colors> select Keyword:

you can set bg/fg color and font size here. see pic:

[image]
[image]

[image][image]
[image]

Comment: No, it didn't work. I tried it now and actually tried to change the color on the item you mentioned and other SQL XXX items as well before, but none worked :(

Comment: Really then something wrong with your vs. its working for me. see pics. I think it will not work for color because of dark theme

Comment: I want to change the color of the "SELECT" and "FROM" parts. Can you change it?

Comment: If you want to change text color then select Plain Text and change color there. see pic for that

Comment: i think you becoming lazy now. now you know where to change simply try all options

Comment: haha. That's the last option I want  to try. Thank you for your time anyway.

Comment: A bad thing is that even if I try all the options, it might not work. I'm guessing this is a vs's theme bug.

Comment: For that you can change color for Keyword property see pic

Comment: Haha but i think you didnt try the keyword option(for sure)

Comment: OH! WOW! You made it. But where is the keyword option??

Comment: Its in same options window under fonts and color simply scroll down. and if it worked for you vote the answer

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH SIR. YOU SAVED MY LIFE. This thing have annoyed me more than a year. lol. And yes, you are right, I didn't try the keyword option.